# Is there a way to create makefile that uses only required .o files?

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to create a makefile that compiles **more than one** program at once. There may be some .cpp files that are used by all of them, and some .cpp files that are used by just one exclusively. The current makefile I have is following:

```
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++14 -MMD -pthread 
TARGETS = server.cpp client.cpp

SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
NON_TARGET_SRC = $(filter-out $(TARGETS),$(SRC))

all: $(TARGETS:%.cpp=%)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf *.d

$(TARGETS:%.cpp=%): % : $(NON_TARGET_SRC:%.cpp=%.o) %.o ###redundant?
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^

-include $(SRC:%.cpp=%.d)
```

Server.cpp and client.cpp are names of files that contain main() function and are supposed to be compiled to executable, rather than .o file. While the above makefile works, I think it does work that is redundant, as it does the final compilation with using all the non-target .o files, while it probably should use only the needed ones (or does the linker pick the needed ones on itself, making such a command's overhead negligible?). So, the question is:

**Is there a way to list .o files that are required by specific program?**

**EDIT:**

The following code seems to work just fine, thanks to packing all the object files into one library file.

```
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++14 -MMD -pthread 
TARGETS = server.cpp client.cpp

LIBRARY_NAME=objects
LIBRARY_FILE=lib$(LIBRARY_NAME).a
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
NON_TARGET_SRC = $(filter-out $(TARGETS),$(SRC))
LDFLAGS = -L.
LDLIBS = -l$(LIBRARY_NAME)

all: $(TARGETS:%.cpp=%)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf *.d
    rm -rf *.a

$(TARGETS:%.cpp=%): % : $(LIBRARY_FILE) %.o
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $*.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

$(LIBRARY_FILE): $(NON_TARGET_SRC:%.cpp=%.o)
    ar rcu $@ $(NON_TARGET_SRC:%.cpp=%.o)
    ranlib $@

-include $(SRC:%.cpp=%.d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do that is to build all object files except those with a `main()` function into a library and link with the library. Building a library is something like this:

```
libfoo.a: $(LIBOFILES)
    ar rcu $@ $(LIBOFILES)
    ranlib $@
```

You'd then also set the Makefile to use the library:

```
LDFLAGS = -L.
LDLIBS  = -lfoo
```

Comment: Thanks for providing actual code to use. I'll try to run it and see if it works correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives me a lot of "undefined reference" errors. Could you check if the commands generated by makefile are corect?
http://pastebin.com/Xkri6SXb

Comment: Thanks for a thorough explanation - I had no idea order of objects matters. The makefile I created with your help works correctly now. I edited post for future reference.

Comment: Just one more thing popped into my head - if the linker skips unnecessary object files, wasn't my original solution equally efficient as this one? (The original solution was to call g++ with all the object files, whether needed or not)

Comment: BTW, doesn't this solution rebuild the executable if library changed? And the library changes whenever any object file changes, so we are back at the beginning, where everything depends on every change :l

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a way to list .o files that are required by specific program?"*

Yeah. List them (or at least the required sources, and substitute) manually.

Also directory search functions could come in handy, but that depends on how your project structure actually looks like.

The easiest way IMHO, is to bundle `.o` files to libraries, the linker will automatically pick what's actually needed for the specific TARGETS.

Comment: Obviously, I want the makefile to be as labourless as possible - so I'd like to escape from manual typing of dependencies. The search functions won't work, because in this scenario, I have all the files in one directory, with .o files for every executable mixed together. And the last solution - packing all .o files to a single library, would also require me to rebuild the whole project, even if just one file is affected, am I right?

Comment: @akrasuski1 _"I have all the files in one directory, with .o files for every executable mixed together."_ That's probably the flaw with your approach. Why not having one directory for the common stuff, and others that just contain the stuff needed for the several TARGET executables. Good organization of source code makes up more than half of the rent. _"would also require me to rebuild the whole project, even if just one file is affected, am I right?"_ Depends on what actually was changed. Usually it's only necessary to rebuild the files affected, as you're already using `.d` dependencies.

Comment: @akrasuski1: No, the library takes a dependency on all the .o files, but the makefile can still rebuild only the sources that changed, preserving the other .o files that are still valid.  Making multiple .o files into a library is a very cheap operation compared to either compiling or linking.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, I never really created a library as such, so I thought it is more like a "big-o-file-of-all-the-files" requiring a full rebuild rather than just a package of actual, single .o files. Thanks for clarification.