# Is it possible to generate list of dependencies for a C++ file?

Tags: c++

I want to create a list of dependencies for particular file. For example:

```
//a.cpp
#include "b.h"
#include <cstdio>
int main(){printf("%d\n",fn());}

//b.h
int fn();

//b.cpp
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
int fn(){return fn2();}

//c.h
inf fn2();

//c.cpp
#include "c.h"
int fn2(){return 5;}
```

For those files, *a* depends on *b* which depends on *c*. So the result of the wanted program should be:

```
a: a.o b.o c.o
```

Yes, it is for makefiles. For some reasons I do not want the list to include ALL `.o` files in directory, so `%.o` won't work. Also, I'm aware of `g++ -MMD` option, and it *almost* works as I want - but it lists only direct dependencies, in this case:

```
a.o: a.cpp b.h
```

(the extensions are not an issue, I can post-process them later)

Is there an easy way for generating such a list?

Comment: I think you can list the `o` files in any order can't you?

Comment: Does `-MD` do what you want? `-MMD` excludes system headers.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes I can. But I don't want to type them manually, and the -MMD option doesn't give *recursive* dependency, just the direct.

Comment: @Wintermute No, the problem is not in system headers being excluded. Read the question again, especially expected result.

Comment: Note that `c.cpp` should `#include "c.h"` (like `b.cpp` already has `#include "b.h"` and `#include "c.h"`) to ensure you get the cross-checking between the client code and provider code.  The header files are the all-important glue that (when properly used) ensure your project is coherent.

Comment: Your right, it was just a simple off-the-top-of-head example, and I made a simple mistake. Editing question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are still going on about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27954273/1120273)... The first thing to understand is that object files **do not** *depend* on other object files. The dependencies list which files are necessary to build something. To create an object file you need some source file and the headers it is using. This is *exactly* the information the variations of the `-MD` flags give you.

If you want to determine which object files are necessary to build an executable, you need something different: you need to create a dependency graph between object files and then create a graph search starting at the node with the entry point (i.e., the `main()` function). The tools to do that are `nm` which prints symbol information of an object an object file and something like `tsort` which, however, just provides a topological order rather than a connected component. However, you could use the same information `tsort` uses to do its job.

The `nm` program just dumps out all symbols defined or referenced in an object file. You'd use all symbols with a capital character to indicate that an object file, i.e., a node, either provides this symbol (if it is something different than `'U'`) or needs that symbol (i.e., the character is `'U'`). The exact meaning of the symbols (e.g., `'T'` for "text", i.e., program code) doesn't matter other than `'U'` meaning "undefined" and everything else being a definition (well, `'W'` may put up a bit of a fight because these are "weak" symbols and multiple translation units may have them). You'd connect two nodes, if one nodes has a symbol undefined and the other has the symbol defined.

Once the graph is build, you'd use the node defining `'main()'` as the start node and search the reachable graph. All object files (nodes) reached are needed to build the corresponding program. That's the algorithmic description. The actual implementation may be different and actually simpler:

1. Use `tsort` to bring the object files into a proper dependency order. If there are cycles, remove them.
2. Start with the object file containing `main()` and record it as a dependency.
3. Record all defined and undefined symbols.
4. Remove each undefined symbol for which there is a defined symbol.
5. If there are no undefined symbols: done.
6. Open the next object file. If there are no more it is an error (you have a cycle and you need to reprocess all objects files on the biconnected component involving the cycle(s).
7. See if there is any defined symbol for which there is an undefined symbol. If not, goto 6.
8. Record the object file as a dependency.
9. Goto 3.

Other than the linker I'm not aware of any tool doing this. The reason is that changing any object file can change the dependencies and you need to reevaluate the dependencies for each program. Incidentally, this is what a linker does.

Maybe you'd get better help if you stated what your actual goal is rather than asking about aspects of the envisioned solution.

Comment: so, basically write a linker :)

Comment: Yes, this is the next part of the previous question. I accepted your answer for that one, but now I noticed it as similar flaw as the original one - see the other question for details. The goal is the same as previously - to create a generic makefile, for which the only thing to be changed are names of files with main function, which compiles anything if and only if it is required.
The only way I am aware of is to somehow generate a list of object files required for creation of exec.
Now, I think I may misunderstand which is the lengthy operation in this process: linking, compilation or both.

Comment: If linking is simple and quick compared to compilation of object files, then I was wrong from the very beginning, and the original solution was acceptable.

Comment: Typically, compilation takes a lot longer than linking. The only system where linking is slow is AIX and even there you get good performance if you `tsort` the library (the reason it is bad is that the algorithm used to process libraries seems to be quadratic rather than linear).

Comment: Ok, then it seems I'm gonna stick to the answer you suggested in the other question. I thought that linking against everything is an issue, but the real bottleneck is still compilation. Thanks for correcting me.